# WindowBuilder SWT Table

Tags: swt, windowbuilder

Can you suggest me how to build a `Table` with `Eclipse WindowBuilder Plugin` and `SWT`?

I read the official docs but I found orrible example with fixed column size. I would like to build a `Table` who fit the parent container (I used `composite`) when it is resized.

P.S.: Maybe I should use `Swing` instead?? All valid example I have seen are with `JTable`..

Can you help me?

Thank you

---

Thank you for your reply!

I have to do a little GUI application for a friend, I'm not so practice nor with `Swing` neither with `SWT`.

Anyway I manage to do a Simple `ApplicationWindow` with `menubar`, some `submenu item` and a `composite` container under the menu where panel should appear when user clicks on menu item.

Than I manage to build a `TableViewer` inside that composite component.. but now I would like add another table in the same place (the table represents different thing and should appear or disappear when user click some menu button).

In Swing I see many example of `CardLayout` but nothing with `SWT`.

Can you suggest me a simple example of layered layout with `SWT`?? I have the impression that Swing is much more simple..

Thank you all

Comment: Note: Mixing SWT and Swing is very difficult, choose either SWT or Swing, not both.

Comment: Is this just an SWT app or is it something like an Eclipse plug-in or RCP which can use Eclipse JFace? Resizable tables and columns are a lot easier using the JFace classes such as TableViewer, TableColumnLayout, ColumnWeightData

Answer (score 0):

On my modest opinion, Swing is well documented than SWT and maybe more simple. I switched to it.

Thank you.